# What may be the reason for JMS or OS not to recognize connection drop?

Tags: networking, network-programming, jms, message-queue, openmq

We have a system with servers communicating over JMS. Sometimes some of the servers can not reconnect after loosing connection to JMS. Loss of connection happens when server restarts, bad network... The reason that prevents reconnecting is "ClientID already in use." error.

> excerpt from JMS log:
>
> "A client on connection guest@10.0.0.106:2390 tried to use client id ABC which is already in use
>
> In-conflict clientID ABC is owned by local connection guest@10.0.0.106:1098"

All servers have distinct clientID. Connection on remote port 1098 existed before server 10.0.0.106 lost connection to JMS. Port 1098 on server ABC is not even open.

I tried using [TCPview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) when the problem occurred. Old connection to server on port 1098 still exists.

I have 2 questions:

Is it possible that JMS sends control packets to nonexistant remote port 1098 without error?

What may be the reason for OS not to recognize connection drop?